# Couchbase storing CAS in object

Tags: database, couchbase, optimistic-locking

I am developing application using Couchbase and I am trying to implement optimistic locking.

I want to store CAS in my stored object, is there a way to add field in JSON so It will be automaticly updated after save ?

Comment: Couchbase already stores a CAS value, so you don't need to implement this yourself. Here's an example using the .NET SDK: https://docs.couchbase.com/dotnet-sdk/2.6/concurrent-mutations-cluster.html